# "рост" не проверочное для "росток"?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово *р**о**ст* не является проверочным для слова *р**о**сток*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правописание корней -РОС-,  -РАСТ-, -РАЩ- не подчиняется фонемному правилу: ***гласную в этом корне нельзя проверять ударением***. Это корень с чередующимися А-О. Принято писать перед СТ и Щ букву А, а перед С букву О: выросли, выращенный, вырастить. Исключения: РОСТОВЩИК РОСТИСЛАВ поехал В РОСТОВ ЗА РОСТКОМ. И ещё слово ОТРАСЛЬ.

Слово РОСТ односложное, О находится в сильной позиции. Проблем в написании слова не возникает, но проверочным для слова РОСТОК оно не является.